# Separating html and JavaScript in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Hey I've got the following problem:

I am building a little flask app, and usually i just stick with bootstrap and jinja templates to get what I want, but this time I needed a bit more customised version. In order to get a grip I started with a simple example of using custom js and flask to get the basic right. But lets go into detail:

Assume I have a simple flask web app called app.py located in my_app/ which looks like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

and the corresponding index.html, which is located in my_app/templates, is simply

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Clicking here will make me dissapear</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">            </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function(event){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

then I see the expected result, that is, i can click on the paragraph to make it disappear.

BUT: I would like to put the javascript part into a main.js file under static/js/. like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function(event){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

and the index.html becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Clicking here will make me dissapear</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='/js/main.js'></script>            
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately nothing will happen. I have tried other ways of referencing the script file as well but until now nothing works. I have the impression im missing something really simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you hit that URL "/js/main.js" in the browser (type it right into the search bar), is the file there?

Comment: Hey Josh, I can see it under http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/js/main.js. Since, as far as i know, Flask looks for such files in the static folder I thought this needed to be omitted. Obviously i was wrong concerning that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simply invoke the [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.url_for) function within the template, referencing the [special static endpoint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#static-files) so that the correct url to the desired target resource be created.  As the desired target is the `main.js` file inside `static/js`, this would lead to the following:

```html
<script type=text/javascript src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='js/main.js')
}}"></script>
```

The rest of the [quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/) guide contains additional useful information.